# Using the non final loop variable inside a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, final, executorservice

I'm trying to execute 100 tasks all in parallel via executors and runnable, the task needs to use the loop variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   executor.execute(() -> {
     doSomething(String.format("Need task number %d done", i));
   }
  });
}
```

I get a squiggly under 'i' saying - `Variable used in lambda expression should be effectively final.`

A loop variable, as far as I'm aware, cannot be made final or effectively final, since it is being changed with each iteration. I found a simple workaround,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   int index = i;
   executor.execute(() -> {
     doSomething(String.format("Need task number %d done", index));
   }
 });
}
```

This doesn't seem the most effective solution to me, declaring a new variable at every iteration. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is local variable, so I think it doesn't really matters

Comment: @ka4eli - agreed. Performance-wise it doesn't matter. JVM most likely will just remove it and use `i` directly. The effectively-final requirement is only enforced by javac, for the sake of programmers. Runtime simply captures the current value.

Comment: @bayou.io very interesting, I didn't think of JVM optimizations.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem and use the same solution.:)  So why index can be seen in the lambda expression but not the loop counter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

I doubt it. Your solution looks fine to me, but if you want you can rewrite it into possibly clearer code like:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(
    i -> executor.execute(
        () -> doSomething(String.format("Need task number %d done", i))
    )
);
```

Comment: This is concise and excellent. I shall use it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

That's the most straightforward way to make it work. You're not going to do better than that.

Comment: agree. unless if we had a util `Iterable<Integer>` - `for(int i: range(0, 100))` - here `i` would be effectively final.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the lambda expression code into the method and call that method into loop this way is the standard lambda expression maintainable code

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){  doSomeThing(i); }


static void doSomeThing(int i)
    { Thread loop=new Thread(()->{print(i);}); // jvm point of view is final
        loop.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        loop.start();
    }
```